# Contexual filter does not work when the page is loaded via AJAX

Tags: ajax, views

I created a node--type.tpl.php file, deactivated all displays (I don't need them), and wrote custom HTML code. I created a view which outputs the list of nodes associated to term. I created it with the contextual filters "Content:Nid" and "Content: Has Taxonomy Term Id." I embedded it to the node I created. (I can activate it as block, because I want to load a whole node with AJAX.)

If I open a node with normal load, the list is beeing showed, but with AJAX load the list is gone. I tried to add an argument to the view like with `views_embed_view('tratata', 'tata', $myarg)`, but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

The module which is responsible of loading a node via AJAX is my custom module, which depends from the [Chaos tool suite](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module.

Comment: `views_embed_view('tratata', 'tata', $myarg)` - here you are passing one argument, but your view has two contextual filters. Are you using default values for the filters? If yes, what are the default values?

Comment: Here are the settings of the filters:

Comment: Here are the settings of the filters: Content:Nid -> Content ID from Url -> exclude; Content: Has Taxonomy Term Id -> Taxonomy term Id from Url -> Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks -> my vocabulary